# unable to install signed apk or build apk - showing "App not installed dialog" - "android-P"

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, android-9.0-pie, android-gradle-3.1.0

I am facing an issue in installing(build or signed) apk in the device showing "App not installed". It's working fine previously, after updating my build tools to "3.1.0" and compile SDK to "android-P" facing this issue,

If I downgrade to "26", showing "drawable-28-alpha" error. Can you please help me with this, tried almost everything.

```
**build.gradle**

compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.***.******"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.4.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


**gradle-wrapper:**
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the detailed error?

Comment: @AmitKumar, I am just getting this “App not installed"on the mobile with the done button while I am installing apk. I am not facing any issue while building the app or in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

On **Android 9 (API 28)** try to disable **Google Play Protect** from play store app.

To disable Google Play Protect. Open "Play Store" application -> tap on Menu button -> select "Play Protect" option -> Click on "Settings" icon -> then disable the option "Scan device for security threats".